# How to implement smooth scrolling on a webpage?

Tags: php, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I want to implement smooth scrolling on my web page. I'm not sure how to do it, either by overriding normal mouse scrolling or maybe there's another way. What I want to achieve is shown e.g. [here](http://www.generateit.net/form-generator/index.php).  Try to scroll through the page.

Comment: What is so special about that page? It seems to scroll just like any other page. Must be something firefox does automatically.

Comment: Yeah by me also this page has no special smooth scrolling. You can catch the scrolling event with jquery and then animate your container's top offset. You should achieve some smooth scrolling.

Comment: Grammar and tag in title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you mention is using this plugin for smooth scrolling:
https://gist.github.com/rennan/5ec8a11302d45cd757e8

If you want the same scrolling results, I recommend using the same plugin instead of building your own version.